# How to read KV via ANT and execute commands on system?

Tags: ant

I'd like to update my `ANT's build.xml` file to:

1. Read a value from the file and
2. Change link on the system to reflect what it read in file

Assume the file to have content in the following format:

```
Environment = dev
```

Further assume directory to have the following files/link:

```
current_env_image -> qa_image.jpg
prod_image.jpg
qa_image.jpg
dev_image.jpg
```

.. where `current_env_image` is a link to whatever the current image should be presented at.

I'd like for an ANT script to:

1. Read the value assigned to Environment (from the file) and
2. Execute a command creating a link to point to the right image:

> unlink current_env_image
>
> ln -s ${environment}_image.jpg current_env_image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the file can be easily done with the [Property task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html):

```
  <property file="foo.properties"/>

reads a set of properties from a file called "foo.properties".
```

Afterwards your variable `Environment` will be set to that value.

The second question could be achieved by the [exec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html)

```
  <exec executable="ln">
    <arg value="-s ${environment}_image.jpg image"/>
  </exec>
```